# changing an element of project file by xml means

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml, csproj

some times I will have to load up to 60 winforms or class library projects into a solution.. and change the output path and reference path for each of them..

so I wrote a wpf application for the same

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var path = txtRootPath.Text;
    var projFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.csproj", SearchOption.AllDirectories);

    foreach (var item in projFiles)
    {
        var xDoc = XDocument.Load(item);
        var outputNodes = xDoc.Root.Descendants("OutputPath");
        foreach (var outoutNode in outputNodes)
        {
            //this part is never hit..
            outoutNode.Value = txtOutputPath.Text;
        }

        //similarly for referencePath
    }

    lblResult.Content = string.Format("Files: {0}", projFiles.Count());
}
```

but `outputNodes` collection will be empty

could somebody please tell what am I doing wrong here

**EDIT:**

I figured out that the problem is with `xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003"` attribute in Project element..

**Solution:**

as given in this solution - 
[Parsing Visual Studio Project File as XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13353628/parsing-visual-studio-project-file-as-xml) 
[Linq-to-XML with XDocument namespace issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11555609/linq-to-xml-with-xdocument-namespace-issue)

Comment: have you tried `xDoc.Descendants` instead of `xDoc.Root.Descendants`

Comment: yes, Its still not working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the default namespace when referring to "OutputPath" element.

```
    XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003";
    var outputNodes = xDoc.Root.Descendants(ns + "OutputPath");
```